# XeLaTeX and microtype protusion problems at hyphens

Tags: xetex, microtype, protrusion

I was excited to learn that XeLaTeX finally has microtype support (I had [asked about that earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100938/hanging-punctuation-in-xelatex)). However, after adding microtype to  my document, I noticed that line breaks at hyphens now go wrong.

Previously, the word `foo-bar` would be hyphenated as:

```
foo-
bar
```

But with microtype enabled, I now get

```
foo-bar
```

and that runs over the right margin.

Is this a known problem, and are there tuning parameters to fix this?

Comment: You've asked five questions already so you probably know that we really need a minimum working example.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: OK, I'll need to concoct one.

Comment: It's actually pretty hard to produce a small example. The problem seems to be tied to using certain fonts, it goes away when I omit the font selection. I'll keep trying.